# How to use `Manager` when using "spawn"

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Here is some pseudocode for what I'm doing

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import Manager

from tqdm import tqdm

def loop(arg):
  # do stuff
  # ...
  results.append(result_of_stuff)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  manager = Manager()
  results = manager.list()

  with mp.get_context('spawn').Pool(4) as pool:
    list(tqdm(pool.imap(loop, ls), total=len(ls)))

  # do stuff with `results`
  # ...
```

So the issue here is that `loop` doesn't know about `results`. I have one working way to do this and it's by using "fork" instead of "spawn". But I need to use "spawn" for reasons beyond the scope of my question..

**So what is the minimal change I need to make for this to work? And I really want to keep `tqdm` hence the use of `imap`**

PS: I'm on Linux

Comment: Note: I think my question might be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11937895/python-multiprocessing-manager-initiates-process-spawn-loop). Waiting for confirmation from someone else. I guess I'd end up asking how using `apply_async` varies from `map`.

Comment: On the above note, I tried it and I'm getting an empty results list, which was the issue I was getting with the snippet in my main post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to add the extra parameters:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import os

from functools import partial
from multiprocessing import Manager

from tqdm import tqdm


def loop(results, arg):
    results.append(len(arg))


def main():
    ctx = mp.get_context("spawn")
    manager = Manager()
    l = manager.list()
    partial_loop = partial(loop, l)

    ls = os.listdir("/tmp")

    with ctx.Pool() as pool:
        results = list(tqdm(pool.imap(partial_loop, ls), total=len(ls)))

    print(f"Sum: {sum(l)}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

There is some overhead with this approach as it will spawn a child process to host the Manager server.

Since you will process the results in the main process anyway I would do something like this instead (but this depends on your circumstances of course):

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import os

from tqdm import tqdm


def loop(arg):
    return len(arg)


def main():
    ctx = mp.get_context("spawn")

    ls = os.listdir("/tmp")

    with ctx.Pool() as pool:
        results = list(tqdm(pool.imap(loop, ls), total=len(ls)))

    print(f"Sum: {sum(results)}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You're right about your follow up remark. I'm at the beginning of my multiprocessing journey so I got carried away when I learned what a manager is

Comment: To be clear for anyone viewing this, I tested the first part of the answer for myself and it works.

Answer (score 2):

I know you have already accepted an answer, but let me add my "two cents":

The other way of solving your issue is by initializing each process in your pool with the global variable `results` as originally intended. The problem was that when using `spawn` newly created processes do not inherit the address space of the main process (which included the definition of `results`). Instead execution starts from the top of the program. But the code that creates `results` never gets executed because of the `if __name__ == '__main__'` check. But that is a good thing because you do not want a separate instance of this list anyway.

So how do we share the same instance of global variable `results` across all processes? This is accomplished by using a *pool initializer* as follows. Also, if you want an *accurate* progress bar, you should really use `imap_unordered` instead of `imap` so that the progress bar is updated in task-completion order rather than in the order in which tasks were submitted. For example, if the first task submitted happens to be the last task to complete, then using `imap` would result in the progress bar not progressing until all the tasks completed and then it would shoot to 100% all at once.

**But Note:** The doumentation for `imap_unordered` only states that the results will be returned in *arbitrary* order, not *completion* order. It does however seem that when a *chunksize* argument of 1 is used (the default if not explicitly specified), the results are returned in completion order. If you do not want to rely on this, then use instead `apply_async` specifying a callback function that will update the progrss bar. See the last code example.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import Manager

from tqdm import tqdm

def init_pool(the_results):
  global results
  results = the_results


def loop(arg):
  import time
  # do stuff
  # ...
  time.sleep(1)
  results.append(arg ** 2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  manager = Manager()
  results = manager.list()

  ls = list(range(1, 10))
  with mp.get_context('spawn').Pool(4, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(results,)) as pool:
    list(tqdm(pool.imap_unordered(loop, ls), total=len(ls)))
  print(results)
```

**Update: Another (Better) Way**

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

from tqdm import tqdm

def loop(arg):
  import time
  # do stuff
  # ...
  time.sleep(1)
  return arg ** 2

if __name__ == '__main__':

  results = []
  ls = list(range(1, 10))
  with mp.get_context('spawn').Pool(4) as pool:
    with tqdm(total=len(ls)) as pbar:
      for v in pool.imap_unordered(loop, ls):
        results.append(v)
        pbar.update(1)
  print(results)
```

**Update: The Safest Way**

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

from tqdm import tqdm

def loop(arg):
  import time
  # do stuff
  # ...
  time.sleep(1)
  return arg ** 2

def my_callback(v):
    results.append(v)
    pbar.update(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':

  results = []
  ls = list(range(1, 10))
  with mp.get_context('spawn').Pool(4) as pool:
    with tqdm(total=len(ls)) as pbar:
      for arg in ls:
        pool.apply_async(loop, args=(arg,), callback=(my_callback))
      pool.close()
      pool.join()
  print(results)
```

Comment: Ah great thank you. I wish I could accept two answers. On another note, is my obsession with tqdm unjustified? I ask because I wonder why it's not standard, and if not, why I don't see it more often in other people's code. If I'm multiprocessing I definitely want to see the progress bar to make sure the last tweak I did had some impact. Even if it's not perfect, it's still probably good enough to see a 50% improvement/degradation. I actually will refuse to do anything without it lol

Comment: I was about to update the answer to recommend that what you really should be doing is to have `loop` just return its results back to the main process, which can then append the results to an ordinary list and then update the progress bar.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the "better" approach. By the way, if you believe this answer is the "better" answer, you *can* un-accept one answer and accept another. I am not saying you *should*; I am saying it is *possible*; I have done it.

Comment: I feel like that better version is the equivalent of `results = list(tqdm(pool.imap_unordered(loop, ls),  total=len(ls))` no (referencing the snippet in the accepted answer)? Unless something else is happening under the hood?